# A problem in building a private network using Ethereum

Tags: network, private

There is a problem in in building a private network using Ethereum.

```
Geth version : 1.8.3 stable
OS & Version : windows 10
```

My scenario is as follows:

1. The genesis block is as follows

   ```
   {
       "config": {
           "chainId"       : 7686,
           "homesteadBlock": 0,
           "eip155Block"   : 0,
           "eip158Block"   : 0
       },
       "nonce"     : "0x0000000000000042",
       "timestamp" : "0x00",
       "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
       "extraData" : "0x00",
       "gasLimit"  : "0x4c4b40",
       "difficulty": "0x400000",
       "mixhash"   : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
       "coinbase"  : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
       "alloc": {
       }
   }
   ```
2. On the first PC(windows10, 192.168.0.7), the following commands is executed

   > bootnode --nodekey=bootnode.key <=== started botstrap node
   >
   > geth --networkid 7686 --datadir "C:\EPN" --ethash.dagdir "C:\EPN" init genesis_block.json
   >
   > geth --networkid 7686 --datadir "C:\EPN" --ethash.dagdir "C:\EPN" --rpc --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3" --rpccorsdomain "*"
   >   --nat "none" --netrestrict "192.168.0.0/16" --syncmode "full" --mine --gasprice 1 --etherbase "0x554C2C877aFc8A8EA0cDD2eA97ea5b5B9A7960e2"
   >   --bootnodes "enode://342a241c8baab9e6ff69a6df015a8dc37df2b477e43338f2e7d98078a115f6b1282e280ed444719d8c5d2bac89837693149771ed10b7bf1e9c1cd13930a270a5@127.0.0.1:30301"
3. On the second PC, the following commands is executed

   > geth --networkid 7686 --datadir "C:\EPN" --ethash.dagdir "C:\EPN" init genesis_block.json
   >
   > geth --networkid 7686 --datadir "C:\EPN" --ethash.dagdir "C:\EPN" --rpc --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3" --rpccorsdomain "*"
   >   --nat "none" --netrestrict "192.168.0.0/16" --syncmode "full"
   >   --bootnodes "enode://342a241c8baab9e6ff69a6df015a8dc37df2b477e43338f2e7d98078a115f6b1282e280ed444719d8c5d2bac89837693149771ed10b7bf1e9c1cd13930a270a5@192.168.0.7:30301"
4. The first PC(windows10) is no problem, on the second PC, however, the following error message is displayed

   ```
   ERROR[04-17|19:26:01]
   ########## BAD BLOCK #########
   Chain config: {ChainID: 7686 Homestead: 0 DAO: <nil> DAOSupport: false EIP150: <nil> EIP155: 0 EIP158: 0 Byzantium: <nil> Constantinople: <nil> Engine: unknown}

   Number: 1
   Hash: 0xcc00615c7554b7c9d8813943e43216e7c4a8dcea6db6e262a8bc6c213d78733c


   Error: invalid mix digest
   ##############################

   WARN [04-17|19:26:01] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=cadcc80d87d6245a err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
   ```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue with you RAM being used up. is your second PC config weaker than first?

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48856704/etherrum-geth-command-shows-retrieved-hash-chain-is-invalid-in-windows-10-powe) similar issue, hope it helps. Running private blockchain is expensive for PC's and laptops. I also suggest you use AWS server